# Another matrices for a semigroup with intermediate growth

Tags: gr.group-theory, matrices, geometric-group-theory, semigroups-and-monoids

Nathanson showed that the Okninski's semigroup $S$ of $2×2$ matrices which is generated by the set $H=\{A,B\}$, where

$
A=\begin{bmatrix}
1&1\\
0&1\\
\end{bmatrix}
,
B=\begin{bmatrix}
1&0\\
1&0\\
\end{bmatrix}
$

has intermediate growth. The importance of his proof is that he used two famous number theoretical results (The Chebyshev theorem about primes and the Hardy-Ramunujan theorem about partitions) to prove it.

> **Question:**
> Is there another pair of matrices with this property, Or they are the only ones?!

Comment: There are plenty of examples in Okninski's book on semigroups of matrices. He also has papers on linear semigroups of intermediate growth.

Comment: See https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S000187080600377X for more on linear semigroups of intermediate growth

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg Thanks

Comment: Other matrices have similar number theoretical proofs, or not?! @BenjaminSteinberg

Comment: I think similar.

Comment: He seems to just use the partition function and not Chebyshev

Comment: His first example is generated by the diagonal idempotent e=diag(1,0,I) and g which is upper triangular with  1,2,1 on the diagonal and 1s above the diagonal.  He shows that growth is bounded above by something of intermediate growth using Hardy-ramanujan and he shows superpolynomial growth by a somewhat messy but elementary counting argument.

Comment: Just for context, there's no example if one assumes that the semigroup consists of invertible matrices. Indeed the [Okninski-Salwa 1995 paper](https://doi.org/10.1016/0022-4049(95)00104-5) says that if a finitely generated subsemigroup of $\mathrm{GL}(n,K)$ has no nonabelian free subsemigroup, then it generates a virtually nilpotent group (and hence has polynomial growth). (In char. zero one can remove "finitely generated".)

Comment: The idea of using the partition function to show a semigroup has intermediate growth is quite common and appears in the note in proof of https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0021869380902136 which gives a very nice example of a finitely presented semigroup of intermediate growth (the detailed proof for the example in the note can be found in a later paper of Kobayashi).